# Grails - URL mapping/default action and flow

Tags: grails

Question -

I've noticed that some applications I test with have calls to another view/controller from an action submit, but when that page is rendered, instead of seeing:

$controller/$page

I see:

$controller/index

Is this an issue with the URL mapping configuration? Default action? Just curious, because it just appears to be the URI mapping to a default instead of the actual action.

view code:

```
<table>
..
<g:actionSubmit class="stats" action="stats" value="View Stats"/>
..
</table
```

controller:

```
def stats() {

    def teamId = Team.get(params.id)
    def allPlayers = Player.withCriteria {
            eq('team', teamId)
            and {
                eq('isActive', true)
            }
    }
    [allPlayers:allPlayers, teamId:params.id]
}
```

UrlMapping:

```
class UrlMappings {

static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
    }
}
}
```

**Edit**

I actually figured out what it is. Which makes me even more confused.

The grails actionSubmit has an action tied to it. That form was just a normal form, without call:

```
<g:form>
<g:actionSubmit class="stats" action="stats" value="View Stats"/>
<g:actionSubmit class="schedule" action="schedule" value="View Schedule"/>
<g:form>
```

So by default, the form redirects the action to $controller/index. If you add an action call in the g:form tag, those two buttons will direct to the correct page, but the URI will now be $controller/$g:form_action.

I guess I don't get the point of the actionSubmit's action if the g:form is needed as a wrapper.

Comment: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-3086

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `index` is the default action for all controllers.  So if you do not specify one, that is the page you will land on for the controller.

It is discussed in further detail on their [website](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.1.1%20Understanding%20Controllers%20and%20Actions).  Namely, the rules are:

> - If only one action is present the default URI for a controller maps to
>     that action.
> - If you define an index action which is the action that
>     handles requests when no action is specified in the URI /book
> - Alternatively you can set it explicitly with the defaultAction property:
>
>   static defaultAction = "list"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Question though - a call from one view using an actionSubmit goes to a method in the controller that has a cooresponding view (named the same thing). Why does the URI go to $controller/index instead of $controller/method?

Comment: Hm, not sure.  Could you post any relevant code relating to your actionSubmit call?

Comment: Added snippet. The stats page renders correctly. Just not the URI.

Comment: It looks correct, like the default mapping.  Is the page you are calling from and the stats action on the same controller?  Also, since your actions are methods and not closures, you are using Grails 2.0, correct?

Comment: Yeah - I figured out why. See above. The cut down response is that the g:form tag dictates the URI, not the g:actionSubmit. Not sure I understand why though.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Yeah this page talks about it briefly: http://grails.org/doc/2.0.1/ref/Tags/actionSubmit.html . You may need to change your URL mappings, or specify it all in the form tag.  Glad you resolved the issue.

Comment: Accepting your answer because the page you gave me assisted me in building the correct answer. Thanks!